# What's exactly primaryAccountIdentifier that should be passed with method canAddSecureElement?

Tags: ios, swift, applepay, apple-wallet

I'm trying to integrate ApplePay InApp Provisioning into my IOS Bank App.

As I press "Add To Apple Wallet" button, I check if pass can be added by checking canAddSecureElementPass(primaryAccountIdentifier:), that returns `true` or `false`. As say documentation, `primaryAccountIdentifier` is "The FPANID (an opaque identifier of the FPAN). The format and value is specified by the issuer’s PNO and is only available after the first provision of a card.".

Can anyone tell me what `primaryAccountIdentifier` exactly is? Is it Bank account Id, cardNumber, cardID or what?

```
internal func isPassKitAvailable() -> Bool {
        let pkPassLibrary = PKPassLibrary()
        let canAddPass = pkPassLibrary.canAddSecureElementPass(primaryAccountIdentifier: "520342378987612")
        return canAddPass 
    }
```

Comment: It is an opaque identifier for the payment identifier that you want to add. It is available from your payment network operator when you request a card to provision